# How can I retain shared folders when cloning VMs using virtualbox and vagrant

Tags: vagrant, virtualbox, shared-directory

First, I am on a Mac. Second, I have a virtualbox VM which was created using vagrant and which uses a shared folder to easily pass files back and forth, etc.

I would now like to clone this VM from a particular state so that I can upgrade an application on it and move forward with it.  The issue is that the only way I know of to use shared folders here is to start the box using `vagrant up` (this makes sense as vagrant mounts the folders as part of its boot process); however, using `vagrant up` always triggers the original VM.

Is there a way to create a clone of a VM using Virtual Box and then to be able to use shared folders so I can easily copy files to and from the host and guest via ssh?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did some more researching and found that I can mount a shared folder in a clone in the same way I can with the original virtualbox VM using:

`mount -t vboxsf -o rw,uid=33,gid=33 <shared_folder_name> <guest_folder>`

Note that the uid and gid specified here relate only to Debian-based systems.  CentOS IDs are different.

For more on the technique and for solutions for CentOS boxes, see here: http://jimmybonney.com/articles/configure_virtualbox_shared_folder_apache_virtual_host/

I've tried the steps in the above article to allow for auto mounting the shared folder when the VM boots, but I've had no success.  As a work-around (which I find acceptable for now), I created an alias in my `.bashrc` file which seems to work fine.

Answer (score 0):

> I would now like to clone this VM from a particular state so that I can upgrade an application on it and move forward with it

one thing you can look is [vagrant snapshot](https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/cli/snapshot.html)

Snapshot works with VirtualBox provider to take a snapshot of your VM at the particular point of time when snapshot is taken. You can then continue working on your VM and when needed you can easily recover from a previous snapshot

Comment: Thanks for this; although I was working with clones, this is very helpful information.